Why does an auto-number field in a Salesforce custom object start from 0 in installed packages?
I have an auto-number field on a custom object in Salesforce, with the starting number explicitly set to 1. This works as expected in my development org, where records begin numbering from 1.
However, when I package this custom object and install the package in another org, the numbering starts from 0 instead of 1.

